# good idea to use list(map(lambda x: xxxx)) without create extra list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pep8

I need to send out request one by one by different id and I have following code but I am wondering if it is good idea to use syntax like `list(map(lambda x: xxxx), id_list)`
or i should just use one-for loop for it?

```
id_list = [1,3,4,100,83,99]
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
url = "https://www.test.com/api/v6/test.json"
response = requests.delete(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers,auth=HTTPBasicAuth(token, 'api_token'))
list(map(lambda x: requests.delete(url, data=json.dumps({'id': x}), headers=headers,auth=HTTPBasicAuth(token, 'api_token')), id_list))
```

Comment: I vote for list comprehensions.

Comment: No, this is entirely for a side-effect, to send a request. You should use a regular loop. Don't use functional programming constructs, like `map` or list comprehensions, for side effects!

Comment: @YOLO Abusing list comprehensions for side effect is bad, and anyway OP wrote  "without create extra list"

Comment: The entire purpose of `map` (and generator expressions) is to lazily produce a new list via some mapping function. Not only is this an abuse of `map` as mentioned above, if you forget to force evaluation of the list in the future, the side effects may not run. If you want to simply loop over a list to carry out side effects, use a plain, imperative loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a for loop.

As @juanpa.arrivillaga and @DeepSpace pointed out - using list comprehensions to perform code that has side-effects is probably not a good idea.

Comment: so what if the lambda inside the map does not have any side-effect like convert all int element of list into string? `map(int, list)` still bad idea?

Comment: @jacobcan118 That is exactly the purpose of `map`, so that would be fine. I believe though that it's generally recommended to use list comprehensions/generator expressions in modern Python instead of `map`.